# Create a firefox profile and start firefox in one command

Tags: command-line, firefox

I am trying to create a firefox profile and launch firefox with that profile in the same command.

I tried:

```
firefox -CreateProfile "test" && firefox -P "test" -no-remote
```

But I am getting the error:

> Firefox is already running, but is not responding. To open a new
>   window, you must first close the existing Firefox process, or restart
>   your system.

It only works if the profile already exists. I need to run this about 5 times at the same time with different profiles.

Is there a way to achieve this via command line? Or a batch file and using `TIMEOUT` would be the solution?

Comment: Perhaps some sleep time between the commands will let the first call to terminate.

Comment: What OS? It works here when I try this under Linux.

Comment: Maybe if we knew more about what your desired result is, we could give you better answers. Looking at the command line options, it does look like you can have separate instances now, as you are requesting, but it doesn't say anything about how that interacts with separate profiles.

Comment: If this is Linux, then the first command should complete and return a status because the `&&` has to be able to determine if the first command succeeded before running the subsequent command - so adding a `sleep` shouldn't help.